# Bounding $X=0$ with Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: probability

I'm looking at a variation of Chebyshev and having a hard time convincing myself why the following is correct:

Given a non-negative, integer valued RV $X$

$$\mathbb{P}(X > 0) \geq 1 - \frac{Var(X)}{\mathbb{E}^2(X)}$$

The proof I'm reading goes:

$$\mathbb{P}(X=0)\overset{1}{\leq} \mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|\geq \mathbb{E}[X])\overset{2}{\leq} \frac{Var(X)}{\mathbb{E}^2(X)}$$

Step 2 is simply the application of Chebyshev, but could someone elucidate why step 1 is correct? Seems trivial but can't wrap my head around it at the moment...

Comment: what's $\mu$? is it $E(X)=\mu$?

Comment: Is this inequality tight?  I would have thought it might be improved to $\mathbb P(X>0) \ge  \dfrac{(\mathbb E[X])^2}{\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]} =\dfrac{(\mathbb E[X])^2}{(\mathbb E[X])^2+\mathrm{Var}(X)} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the r.v. is integer valued and non-negative, the event $\{X=0\}$ is equal to the event $\{X\leq 0\}$, which in turn is equivalent to $\{X-E(X)\leq -E(X)\}$.

Notice that $\{|X-E(X)|\geq E(X)\}=\{X-E(X)\geq E(X)\}\cup\{-(X-E(X))\geq E(X)\}$, which in turn equals $\{X-E(X)\geq E(X)\}\cup\underbrace{\{(X-E(X))\leq -E(X)\}}_{\{X=0\}}$.

Notice that if event  $\{X=0\}$ is verified then  $\{|X-E(X)|\geq E(X)\}$ is verified, in terms of set inclusions this means that $\{X=0\}\subset \{|X-E(X)|\geq E(X)\}$. Translated to probabilities this is equivalent to the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I guess $\mu=\mathbb E[X]$. Since $X\geq 0$ a.s., $$X=0\iff X\leq 0\iff X-\mathbb E[X]\leq -\mathbb E[X]\implies |X-E[X]|\geq \mathbb E[X].$$

Comment: Not sure I follow, why is the last step correct?
Also you omitted the probabilities. Are you saying they're equal?

Comment: Because if $a\geq 0$, then $|x|\geq a\iff x>a$ or $x<-a$. For your last remark, I won't do all the work . I have largely enough information to conclude. @ec2604

Comment: I understand your comment w.r.t my first remark.
Not sure why you're saying you won't do all the work...I didn't fully understand your answer to my question.

Comment: @ec2604: If $A\subset B$, then $\mathbb P(A)\leq \mathbb P(B)$. Does it helps you to conclude ?